# New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Though I know the answer, I just thought I would drop this question here for anyone else that comes across this error message. There doesn't seem to be anything coming up in my search results.

When running an Azure Resource Manager Template with this command:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -WhatIf -ResourceGroupName my-rg -TemplateFile my-rg-tst-parameters.json -TemplateParameterFile .\my-rg-tst-parameters.json
```

I'm getting this error:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters
> for the cmdlet. Parameter type in parameters cannot be null or empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error in this case is caused because the command being run is passing the parameter file where it should be parsing the template file. The correct command would be:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -WhatIf -ResourceGroupName my-rg -TemplateFile .\my-rg-template.json -TemplateParameterFile .\my-rg-tst-parameters.json
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly, bicep is not installed on your machine. to check installation run "bicep --version". If no output then bicep can be installed by running the command
winget install -e --id Microsoft.Bicep
Make sure that Visual Stdio Code or Command prompt is open with admin rights. After installation, check System Environment variable has the installation path or not. Do not check User Environment Variables.